# When already connected with eth0, Network manager still tries to connect wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager, wired

I have a solid working network and internet connection through eth0, but network manager still automatically tries to connect to wifi. Since the wifi is unreliable, this is just trying and failing over and over again, but even with decent wifi, I don't want both connections.

How do I configure it to not attempt to connect wlan0 if eth0 is connected?

```
# NetworkManager.conf:
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Please click the Network Manager icon and uncheck 'Enable Wireless.' Please check here: [image]

Comment: Yes, I could turn off the wifi antenna, but I shouldn't have to. Network manager used to be much better about trying the wifi while connected to ethernet, but nowadays it just keeps trying and trying when it can't succeed and doesn't need to.

Comment: Is your NetworkManager.conf file as installed by default or edited?

Comment: It's default from the package manager. I added it to my question, above.